# github3.py login using ssh keys

Tags: python, github-api, github3.py

Is there a way to use github3.py python library to access github with a SSH key?
I'm trying to create a service that writes on some repositories using a machine user for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the GitHub API doesn't provide a way to authenticate with SSH keys. Thus, github3.py provides no way to login using SSH keys.

Comment: I might have misunderstood this link then : https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/ (read under Machine User at the end)

Comment: You did. Deploy keys are meant to orchestrate a deploy to a server, e.g., allow GitHub to SSH into your server to perform the Deploy. It sounds like you want to use SSH keys to authenticate to GitHub though and that's not possible via the API